# Project in Oracle Weblogic 12.1.2 deploys, but in 12.1.1 doesn't

Tags: oracle, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have a Java EE Maven project that was reportedly deployed in an Oracle Weblogic 12.1.1 server successfully. By mistake I deployed it first to a local Oracle Weblogic 12.1.2 server for development and there weren't any problems. After finding out about the correct Weblogic version I installed locally Oracle Weblogic 12.1.1 and attempted to deploy the project there using Eclipse Kepler 4.3.

To my surprise, the project couldn't be deployed, throwing the following exceptions:

```
<Jul 12, 2014 5:40:08 PM CDT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "1405204805509" for task "0". Error is: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.atmosphere.cpr.AsyncSupportListener"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.atmosphere.cpr.AsyncSupportListener
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.atmosphere.cpr.AsyncSupportListener
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Jul 12, 2014 5:40:08 PM CDT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating distribute task for application "_auto_generated_ear_".> 
<Jul 12, 2014 5:40:08 PM CDT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.atmosphere.cpr.AsyncSupportListener
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.atmosphere.cpr.AsyncSupportListener
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

By "not deploying" I mean that apparently the WAR wasn't even published to Weblogic since the project's URL returns a 404 error.

The stack shows that there is a missing Java class which is: org.atmosphere.cpr.AsyncSupportListener, although I'm not making use of that class in my project.

I attempted to fix the issue by adding the corresponding dependency for the missing package ("org.atmosphere.cpr") to the pom.xml, but after doing so other exceptions appeared showing that classes related to JBoss and Jetty were missing, though I also don't use any of those components in the project.

This same situation happens in both environments I have: one in Mac OS X Mavericks and another in Windows 8.

Could someone give me some guidance about how to fix this problem?

Comment: You received some answers here about version dependencies, were they helpful? https://community.oracle.com/thread/3583447

Comment: Not exactly, since I also tried using the supposedly compatible versions of Eclipse with Oracle Weblogic 12.1.1 but they all threw the same errors. Tried Eclipse Kepler 4.3 and the Indigo version distributed as part of the bundled package in one of the downloads of Oracle Weblogic 12.1.1 Server